# How to show a dropdown menu on a underlined word in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to underline a word and show a dropdown menu on that underlined word. Sounds simple but I'm having problem trying to get the final result. There's a hard coded version but I want to know how to do it dynamically. The problem that I want to solve is when I write a paragraph and click analyze, a progressbar would be displayed. if I click on the progressbar, a underline would be there over a certain word and then it will display a dropdown menu. Clicking on any of the word in the drop down menu should then replace the original underlined word.

Suppose if a person enters this bit of text: 
`"Collective people are doing the work. The work should be easy now"`

My main problem is that how should I work with this new response. as you will see in my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-cookies-yi8z7), I've just hardcoded {joy: collective.....} but this new response breaks the paragraph into a sentence array and also gives sentence number as to where to show the underline in the word, how would I show the underline in that particular sentence with their respective recommended words.

Here's the new response from the api:

```
"sentence": [
    "Collective people are doing the work.",
    "The work should be easy now."
  ],
"recommendations": {
    "joy": {     //for joy progressbar
      "0": {    //first {element/sentence} in the above sentence array
        "collective": [
          "inner",
          "constant"
        ]
      }
    },
    "happy": {
      "1": { 
        "easy": [
          "yes",
          "accessible"
        ]
      }
   }
}
```

Right now in my example, there's only one progressbar, but there can be two progressbars too. But for now, if we click on the joy progressbar, then the 'collective' word on the first sentence should be underlined and a drop down menu would be there.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-cookies-yi8z7)

The code

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Content, Dropdown, Label, Progress, Button, Box } from "rbx";

import "rbx/index.css";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [serverResponse, setServerResponse] = useState(null);
  const [text, setText] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [modifiedText, setModifiedText] = useState(null);
  const [selectedSentiment, setSentiment] = useState(null);
  const [dropdownContent, setDropdownContent] = useState([]);
  const [isCorrected, setIsCorrected] = useState(false);
  const [displayDrop, setDisplayDrop] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (serverResponse && selectedSentiment) {
      const newText = Object.entries(serverResponse[selectedSentiment]).map(
        ([word, recommendations]) => {
          const parts = text[0].split(word);
          const newText = [];
          parts.forEach((part, index) => {
            newText.push(part);
            if (index !== parts.length - 1) {
              newText.push(
                <u
                  className="dropbtn"
                  data-replaces={word}
                >
                  {word}
                </u>
              );
            }
          });

          return newText;
        }
      );

      setModifiedText(newText.flat());
    }
  }, [serverResponse, text, selectedSentiment]);

  const handleAnalysis = () => {
    setLoading(true);

    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false);
      setServerResponse({ joy: { collective: ["inner", "constant"] } });
    }, 1500);
  };

  const handleTextChange = event => {
    setText([event.target.innerText]);
  };

  const handleSentClick = () => {
    let senti = "joy";
    let col = text[0];
    setSentiment(senti);
    setDropdownContent(serverResponse[senti].collective);
    setDisplayDrop(true);
  };

  const replaceText = wordToReplaceWith => {
    const replacedWord = Object.entries(serverResponse[selectedSentiment]).find(
      ([word, recommendations]) => recommendations.includes(wordToReplaceWith)
    )[0];

    setText([
      text[0].replace(new RegExp(replacedWord, "g"), wordToReplaceWith)
    ]);
    setModifiedText(null);
    setServerResponse(null);
    setIsCorrected(true);
    setDropdownContent([]);
  };

  const hasResponse = serverResponse !== null;

  return (
    <>
      <div className="dropdown-n">
        <div
          contentEditable
          onInput={handleTextChange}
          style={{ border: "1px solid red", width: "300px", height: "30px" }}
        >
          {hasResponse && modifiedText
            ? modifiedText.map((text, index) => <span key={index}>{text}</span>)
            : isCorrected
            ? text[0]
            : ""}
        </div>
        {/* {displayDrop ? ( */}
        <div
          id="myDropdown"
          class="dropdown-content-n"
          onClick={() => setDisplayDrop(false)}
        >
          {dropdownContent.map((content, index) => (
            <span onClick={() => replaceText(content)} key={index}>
              {content}
            </span>
          ))}
        </div>
        {/* ) : null} */}
      </div>
      <Button
        color="primary"
        onClick={handleAnalysis}
        disabled={loading || text.length === 0}
      >
        analyze
      </Button>
      {hasResponse && (
        <Label>
          Joy{" "}
          <Progress
            value={Math.random() * 100}
            color="info"
            onClick={handleSentClick}
          />
        </Label>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```